# How to constraint an image to the bottom of the View Controller on iPhone X (below home indicator)

Tags: ios, swift, iphone-x

I have a view controller that looks fine on all devices but leaves an undesired white padding behind the Home Indicator on iPhone X. I would like my background image to extend all the way to the bottom margin, and be behind the home indicator like, for example, a tab bar does.

[image]

I realize that I could use negative margin over the image, but then that means that I am cutting part of it on other devices. I also setting a parameter to "prefer hiding the home indicator" but it simply hides the bar, and does not extend the image to the margin.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Finally got to a solution!

First of all, you need to either use a "new" View Controller that contains the Safe Area Layout Guides, or activate them on the Document tab of the View Controller:

[image]

After this, you need to realize that a safe area is the view from above the Home Indicator up to below the Status Bar. However, once Safe Area Layout Guides are activated, if you set a constraint to the bottom of the superview, it will go beyond the Safe Area and into the actual bottom (or top if so desired) of the View Controller.

Hope this helps!